# How to prevent trailing newline in PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

This code adds lines, even when using "-NoNewline"

```
$LST1="OsName","OsVersion","TimeZone","CsName"
$LST2="CsManufacturer","CsModel","CsSystemType","BiosBIOSVersion","BiosReleaseDate"
$MEM1 = (Get-CimInstance Win32_PhysicalMemory | Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum | Foreach {"{0:N2}" -f ([math]::round(($_.Sum / 1GB),2))})
$Pro1 = "systemname","DeviceID","numberOfCores","NumberOfLogicalProcessors"

Add-Content OutText.txt "OS Information:" -NoNewline
Get-ComputerInfo -Property $LST1 | Format-List | Out-File -Encoding ASCII -FilePath OutText.txt -Append
Add-Content OutText.txt "Hardware Information:" -NoNewline
Get-ComputerInfo -Property $LST2 | Format-List | Out-File -Encoding ASCII -FilePath OutText.txt -Append
Add-Content OutText.txt "RAM: $RAM1 GB" -NoNewline
Get-WmiObject -class win32_processor -Property  $Pro1 | Select-Object -Property $Pro1 | Out-File -FilePath OutText.txt -Encoding ASCII -Append
```

Too many lines breaks:

[image: Too many lines breaks]

Comment: Use something like `(Get-ComputerInfo -Property $LST1 | Format-List | Out-String).Trim() | Add-Content -Path $path -NoNewline`

Comment: That did it, THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 5):

[Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) has provided the crucial pointer in a comment:

```bash
(Get-ComputerInfo -Property $LST1 | Format-List | Out-String).Trim() | 
  Add-Content -Path $path -NoNewline
```

Let me elaborate:

- To prevent leading and trailing empty lines in the output of `Format-List` from showing up in a file via [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) / `>`, **use [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) to create an *in-memory* string representation of the formatted output first**,
- which then allows you to apply **[`.Trim()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Trim)** to the resulting multi-line string in order to **remove leading and trailing lines (whitespace in general) from `Out-String`'s output**.

Since `Out-String` itself renders the formatting instructions output by `Format-List`, you can then use [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) or [`Add-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content) to save / append the resulting *string* to a file.

---

##### The behavior of `Out-String`:

`Out-String` produces the same *for-display* representation that you get by default in the console - or via other `Out-*` cmdlets, notably [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) / `>` - as a *single*, *multi-line* string by default.

While this representation may *itself* contain empty lines, as is typical, **`Out-String` *additionally* appends a trailing newline, even though there's no good reason to do so**, as discussed in [GitHub issue #14444](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14444).

In cases where you want **to remove this extraneous trailing newline *only***, you can use the following approach, via the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) (the operation works with both Windows-style CRLF newlines (`\r\n`) and Unix-style LF-only ones (`\n`)):

```bash
(... | Out-String) -replace '\r?\n\z'
```

Or, less efficiently, using the `-Stream` switch to output lines *individually* and then re-join them with newlines *without* a trailing one (`` "`n" `` creates a LF-only newline, which PowerShell accepts interchangeably with CRLF newlines (`` "`r`n" ``):

```bash
(... | Out-String -Stream) -join "`n"
```

**`Out-String` applied to output *from external programs*:**

`Out-String` can also be used to capture the lines output by external programs *as a single, multi-line string* (by default, PowerShell captures output *line by line*, resulting in an *array* of strings when captured in a variable).

However, this use of `Out-String` is **problematic**:

- There too the trailing newline that is appended can be a nuisance.
- In *Windows PowerShell* there's an additional nuisance (which has since been corrected in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*): If you use a `2>&1` to merge stderr output into the success output stream, the first stderr line is formatted *like a PowerShell error*.

  - Run `cmd /c 'echo yes & echo no >&2' 2>&1 | Out-String` to see the problem.

The following **idiom avoids both problems** (`...` represents your external-program call):

```bash
$multiLineString = [string[]] (... 2>&1) -join "`n"
```

<sup>Note: The above uses a LF-only newline to join the array elements, which is usually sufficient. Use `` "`r`n" `` for CRLF newlines or `[Environment]::NewLine` for the *OS-appropriate* newline sequence.</sup>

**Example**:

The following `cmd.exe` CLI call outputs both a stdout line and a stderr line, with `2>&1` on the PowerShell side merging the two into the success output stream.

```bash
PS> [string[]] (cmd /c 'echo yes & echo no >&2' 2>&1) -join "`n" |
      ForEach-Object { "[$_]" } # just to visualize the string boundaries 
[yes 
no ]
```

<sup>Note: The trailing space after `no` is owed to the unusual behavior of `cmd.exe`'s built-in `echo` command: it *includes* the space before the `>&2` redirection in its output.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to strip the Cr/Lf added by Out-String.

```
$YourVariableHere = $($YourVariableHere.Substring(0,($YourVariableHere.Length-2)))
```

You can adjust the number at the end if there is more than one Cr/Lf you want to remove.

HTH

Comment: That works (with CRLF, but not LF), but note that the enclosing `$(...)` is unnecessary (and, in general, can have side effects). A more concise (though perhaps conceptually more complex, regex-based) solution that works with both CRLF and LF-only newlines is: `$YourVariableHere -replace '\r?\n\z'`.  `'(?:\r?\n)+\z'` would remove all trailing newlines;  `'(?:\r?\n){2}\z'` would remove `2`, for instance.