# Split string with "-"

Tags: powershell, split

```
System.Management.Automation.RemoteException
name: CLD:HYB_Z_BASIS_ADMIN_SUPER
description: Basis Administrator
readOnly: 
roleReferences:
- roleTemplateAppId: it!b2455
  roleTemplateName: AuthGroup_Administrator
  name: AuthGroup_Administrator
- roleTemplateAppId: it!b2455
  roleTemplateName: AuthGroup_BusinessExpert
  name: AuthGroup_BusinessExpert
OK
```

I have above string, each line is delimited by CRLF. I am trying to extract and split below information into two rows delimited with "-" so I can get array of two rows but I am not getting correct result.

My code is:

```
$Myarray = $string -split "-"

- roleTemplateAppId: it!b2455
  roleTemplateName: AuthGroup_Administrator
  name: AuthGroup_Administrator
- roleTemplateAppId: it!b2455
  roleTemplateName: AuthGroup_BusinessExpert
  name: AuthGroup_BusinessExpert
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches) method to extract *multiple* matches from a string:

```bash
$string = @'
System.Management.Automation.RemoteException
name: CLD:HYB_Z_BASIS_ADMIN_SUPER
description: Basis Administrator
readOnly: 
roleReferences:
- roleTemplateAppId: it!b2455
  roleTemplateName: AuthGroup_Administrator
  name: AuthGroup_Administrator
- roleTemplateAppId: it!b2455
  roleTemplateName: AuthGroup_BusinessExpert
  name: AuthGroup_BusinessExpert
OK
'@

# Find all matches for the given regex and return the matched
# text (.Value) for each.
# Returns 2 three-line strings.
[regex]::Matches($string, '(?m)^- .+\n.+\n.+').Value
```

<sup>Note: The solution relies on a *single, multi-line* string as input. If you have an *array* of strings, join them with `[Environment]::NewLine` first; e.g. `$multilineString = 'foo', 'bar' -join [Environment]::NewLine`; you can also apply this technique to output captured from *external programs* - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68778998/45375).</sup>

For a detailed **explanation of regex `(?m)^- .+\n.+`** and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/gZzY7X/3).

Note:

- As of PowerShell 7.3.x, `-match`, PowerShell's [regular-expression matching operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch), only ever finds at most *one* match; the need to resort to a .NET API for *multiple* matches introduces significant complexity; [GitHub issue #7867](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7867) proposes introducing a `-matchall` operator to remedy that - while the proposal has been green-lit, no one has stepped up to implement it yet.

---

As for **what you tried**:

`-split "-"`:

- tokenizes the *entire* string, so you'll get unrelated information that requires post-filtering
- *excludes* the `-` from the resulting tokens (since they act as the *separators*), which makes it harder to filter out the relevant tokens
- doesn't limit the tokens to only their first 2 lines.

A solution using [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split), *is* possible, but requires additional use of [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch), which makes the solution both more complex and less efficient:

```bash
# Same output as above.
$string -split '(?m)(^- .+\n.+\n.+)' -match '^- '
```

Enclosing the relevant part of the regex in `(...)`, i.e. making it a *capture group*, causes `-split` to *include* the group's matches in the tokens returned; `-match '^- '` then filters out all tokens that do *not* start with `-` , leaving only the 2 two-line strings of interest.