# how to get the value in a string using regex

Tags: regex, powershell, capture-group

I am confused on how to get the number in the string below. I crafted a regex

```
$regex = '(?s)^.+\bTotal Members in Group: ([\d.]+).*$'
```

I need only the number part `2` inside a long string a line reads  `Total Members in Group: 2`.

My `$regex` returns me the entire line but what i really need is the number.

The number is random

Comment: Try `'Total Members in Group: (\d+)'`. The number is in the first capture group, not the entire match

Comment: How you are matching your regex?

Comment: In case you're using `-match` with a single input string: If a match is found, `$Matches.1` contains what the first and only capture group (`([\d]+)`, which can be simplified to `(\d+)`) captured.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM This is where I am not sure.

Comment: I am still not getting just the number ```$String = 'Total Members in Group: 2'
$regex = '(?s)^.+\bTotal Members in Group: (\d+).*$'
$String -match $regex``` This gives me ```true``` but what is the number @mklement0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cls
$string = 'Total Members in Group: 2'
$membersCount = $string -replace "\D*"
$membersCount
```

One more way:

```
cls
$string = 'Total Members in Group: 2'
$membersCount = [Regex]::Match($string, "(?<=Group:\s*)\d+").Value
$membersCount
```

Answer (score 1):

[Fors1k's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69620128/45375) shows elegant solutions that *bypass* the need for a capture group (`(...)`) - **they are the best solutions for the *specific* example in the question**.

To answer the ***general* question** as to how to extract substrings
**if and when capture groups *are* needed**, the PowerShell-idiomatic way is to:

- Either: Use **`-match`**, the [regular-expression matching operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) with a *single* input string: if the `-match` operation returns `$true`, the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches) reflects what the regex captured, with property (key) `0` containing the full match, `1` the first capture group's match, and so on.

  ```sh
  $string = 'Total Members in Group: 2'
  if ($string -match '(?s)^.*\bTotal Members in Group: (\d+).*$') {
    # Output the first capture group's match
    $Matches.1
  }
  ```

  - Note:

    - `-match` only ever looks for *one* match in the input.
    - Direct use of the underlying .NET APIs is required to look for *all* matches, via `[regex]::Matches()` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69534731/45375) for an example.
    - While `-match` only populates `$Matches` with a *single* input string (with an *array*, it acts as a *filter* and returns the sub-array of matching input strings), you can use a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement with `-Regex` to apply `-match` behavior to an *array* of input strings; here's a simplified example (outputs `'1', '2', '3'`):

      ```sh
      switch -Regex ('A1', 'A2', 'A3') {
        'A(.)' { $Matches.1 }
      }
      ```

- Or: Use **`-replace`**, the [regular-expression-based string replacement operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator), to match the *entire* input string and replace it with a reference to what the capture group(s) of interest captured; e.g, `$1` refers to the first capture group's value.

  ```sh
  $string = 'Total Members in Group: 2'
  $string -replace '(?s)^.*\bTotal Members in Group: (\d+).*$', '$1'
  ```

  - Note:

    - `-replace`, unlike `-match`, looks for *all* matches in the input
    - `-replace` also supports an *array* of input strings, in which case each array element is processed separately (`-match` does too, but in that case it does *not* populate `$Matches`; as stated, `switch` can remedy that).
    - A caveat re `-replace` is that if the regex does *not* match, the *input string is returned as-is*